# MS Access how to set orientation of a control via VBA code

Tags: controls, orientation

I got this code where I try to change the direction of a control to RtL orientation.
I' stuck!

```
Private Sub Notes_GotFocus()
  Me.Controls("Notes").Properties("Orientation") = ac something according to help...`
```

orientation =1 means RTL

Please help
Avri

I set the value to "1" But no success
there's no ac command for that property either

Answer (score 0):

After a long deeging :):):)
Here's the solution to the alignment/orientation:

```
Private Sub Notes_GotFocus()
       Me.Controls("Notes").TextAlign = 3
       Call ActivateKeyboardLayout(Heb, True)
   End Sub
```

The control name is Notes. It it a Long Text field. When it gets the focus, the writing orientation is changed to RtL and the language to Hebrew.
TextAlign = 3 meand RTL